# Call script inside if statement Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

Im trying to conditionally call script depending of language in Wordpress with polylang. I can see the script in Google Inspector but it doesn't work. Script works correctly in customizer.
Code:

```
<?php 

if(pll_current_language() == 'en') : ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    const cartBtn = document.querySelector('.cart button');
const formCart = document.querySelector('div.product.elementor form.cart');
var newBtn = document.createElement('a');
newBtn.innerHTML = "<h1>Back to shop</h1>";
newBtn.classList.add('cart-custom-link');
newBtn.setAttribute("href", "/shop/");

cartBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
   formCart.appendChild(newBtn);
   console.log('click');
});

</script>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php 
if(pll_current_language() == 'uk') : ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    const cartBtn = document.querySelector('.cart button');
const formCart = document.querySelector('div.product.elementor form.cart');
var newBtn = document.createElement('a');
newBtn.innerHTML = "<h1>Повернутися до магазину</h1>";
newBtn.classList.add('cart-custom-link');
newBtn.setAttribute("href", "/shop-uk/");

cartBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
   formCart.appendChild(newBtn);
   console.log('click');
});

</script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Is there any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My assumption why the code does not work is because the script code is added (and therefore run) before the DOM tree is ready. Thus, it has to be wrapped in a `window.onload` handler (or jQuery's `$(document).ready();`). Also, copy&pasting the JS code for every language isn't really pretty. There's a cleaner solution:

- place the code in a .js-file
- use a JS-object for the text to be translated
- enqueue the script, then use `wp_localize_script()` on it

like so:
`my_cart.js`

```
window.onload = function () {
  const cartBtn = document.querySelector('.cart button');
  const formCart = document.querySelector('div.product.elementor form.cart');
  var newBtn = document.createElement('a');
  newBtn.innerHTML = "<h1>"+cart_localize.back_to_shop+"</h1>";
  newBtn.classList.add('cart-custom-link');
  newBtn.setAttribute("href", "/shop-uk/");

  cartBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    formCart.appendChild(newBtn);
    console.log('click');
  });
}
```

Next, within PHP, enqueue the script like so:

```
function load_localized_scripts() {
  $cart_localize = array(
    'back_to_shop' => 'Back to shop', // default
  );
  if (pll_current_language() == 'uk') {
    $cart_localize['back_to_shop'] = 'Повернутися до магазину';
  }
  if (pll_current_language() == 'de') {
    $cart_localize['back_to_shop'] = 'Zurück zum Shop';
  }
  wp_enqueue_script('my-cart', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'js/my_cart.js');
  wp_localize_script('my-cart', 'cart_localize', $cart_localize); 
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_localized_scripts');
```

The `$cart_localize` array may contain as many key → value pairs of label => text translation as you like. It is inserted into the JavaScript object named like the 2nd argument of the `wp_localized_script` function. Then, you can access it within JS using `cart_localize.key_name`.

Technically, you can also register a Polylang string using `pll_register_string` named `back_to_shop` and easily insert the translations you entered under Languages → String translations using the `pll__()` function:

```
    $cart_localize['back_to_shop'] = pll__('back_to_shop');
```

I won't fully cover this here, since I'm not sure this matches the way you want to manage translations.

Comment: Thx for help. How i can correctly enqueue script? And where i should put php code? In functions.php?

Comment: If you do not want to make your own plugin - yes, you can put it into your theme's or child theme's functions.php. Next, place your custom JS file (e.g., my_cart.js) in your active theme's directory (e.g., wp-content/themes/my_theme/js/my_cart.js - if the `js` subdirectory doesn't exist, create it). Then, you can enqueue it with `  wp_enqueue_script('my-cart', get_template_directory() . '/js/my_cart.js');`. Make sure the script and directory are readable for the webserver.

Comment: So I put php snippet in functions.php with  wp_enqueue_script('my-cart', get_template_directory() . '/assets/js/my_cart.js'); line. And put js in /wp-content/themes/oceanwp/assets/js but it still not work. Maybe you can check [website?](https://prostir.shop/) is there any changes in DOM?

Comment: Whoops, sorry. My bad.. I accidentally wrote get_template_directory() instead of get_template_directory_uri(). Change the enqueue script line to: `wp_enqueue_script('my-cart', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/my_cart.js');`